# Android orientation change in video player

Tags: java, android, orientation

I have a Video Player. And want to enable both landscape and portrait orientation. But the problem is that player downloading the file every time, when orientation is changed.
I've tried to use "onCofigurationChange", but it is still not working.
How I can solve the problem?

P.S. I have already changed my AndroidManifest.xml file and added

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

so the problem is somewhere in my java file.

Here is my code:

```
public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog pDialog;
VideoView videoview;

String VideoURL = "http://v.mover.uz/ep83Sfim_s.mp4";


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    else
    {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
    }

    //        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


    setupActivity();

}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);

    setupActivity();
}

public void setupActivity() {
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
            // Create a progressbar
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoViewActivity.this);
    // Set progressbar message
    pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Show progressbar
    pDialog.show();

    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                VideoViewActivity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoURI(video);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            videoview.start();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: i think you should add some code in onDestroy of your activity. because everytime screen orientation change, the activity will be destroyed first

Comment: just remove your code from onConfigurationChanged method and add simple after super    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
in that.it works.

Comment: I've tried it, but it not works((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onConfigurationChanged` should be:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    //if you need change layout then do:  
    switch(newConfig.orientation) {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            setContentView(layout_landscape)
            break;
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            setContentView(layout_portrait);
            break;
    }
}
```

No need call `setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main) and setupActivity()` again.

And also need add `<activity android:name="<Your_video_avtivity>" android:configChanges="orientation" />` in your AdroidManifest.

Comment: I hoped it would work finally, but video is re-downloading again when the orientation is changed

Comment: It should not, because using `onConfigurationChanged` then activity not destroy and restart.

Comment: do you have `<activity android:name="<video_avtivity>" android:configChanges="orientation" /> `in your menifest? if not then add it

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".VideoViewActivity"
           android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>

    </application>

Comment: My Android Manifest is given above. Now, when I added it, Video plays only till the phone's orientation is changed. When I changed it to landscape, programm stops working. But I want the player continued playing the video

Comment: I've changed the code in onConfigurationChanged to this: "getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)" and now it works.

Comment: The problem was that I've write android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" to the MainActivity. Now, when I've changed it in VideoViewActivity and changed the code, it works properly. Thank you very much!